# REST client in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, client

I am creating a REST Client in Java,server accepts and responds in XML, I am using JAXB for this.but order in not preseved. Is there any way that I can pass plain text string to same and not use JAXB for this.

Thanks

Comment: Preserve the XML order?  Do you control the schemas?

Comment: What order exactly? Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: what basically I mean it is XML,but I want to treat it is a String. It is possible.

Comment: Are you sure you unmarshall List, not Set?